# How to handle json array data

Tags: arrays, json

I want to use this JSON file from google in my HTML page?
But I am not understanding any of the material on google? Please help out on how to parse this json file to the HTML page

https://storage.googleapis.com/android-tv/android_tv_videos_new.json

This is the link for JSON file, Please help. I am new to website build. Also HTML page code.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you probably want to use javascript.

Comment: Yes please, i tried some on my own but still I can't             ```<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

data="https://storage.googleapis.com/android-tv/android_tv_videos_new.json"
var obj = JSON.parse(data.googlevideos);

for (var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj[i].category;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>```